# How ca i set Background Color in my JInternalFrames?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I need to set the background color in my JInternalFrames. I couldn't.

JInternalFrame frm = new JInternalFrame();
frm.setBackground(Color.red);

This don't work.

You knows how can i do this?

Thanks You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing windows (JFrame, JDialog ...) and internal frames use a "content pane" to hold child components. So you need to set the background of the content pane:

```
internalFrame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.RED );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Top Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for more information.

Keep a link to the Swing tutorial handy for all the Swing basics.

Answer (score 0):

try calling setOpaque(true) on the JInternalFrame